# Firebase default notification color is not visible in Samsung

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, samsung-mobile

Firebase default notification color is not visible when the app is in the background state. Here is the manifest file configuration -

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification_white" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/green" />
```

It works in every mobile device except Samsung, targeting Android OS version above lollipop.

Here is the Firebase version, using in the project.

```
 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
```